# Drools engine hangs during multiple statefulsession Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, drools, rete

For every request, I create a fresh knowledge session, execute the rules and eventually dispose it. This works fine with few requests in Development environment.
But in production environment, with multiple requests the Drools engine hangs with below thread dump.

```
`java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.drools.reteoo.JoinNodeLeftTuple.getLastHandle(JoinNodeLeftTuple.java:536)
at org.drools.reteoo.AccumulateNode.addMatch(AccumulateNode.java:862)
at org.drools.reteoo.AccumulateNode.modifyRightTuple(AccumulateNode.java:558)
at org.drools.reteoo.RightInputAdapterNode.modifyLeftTuple(RightInputAdapterNode.java:222)
at org.drools.reteoo.SingleLeftTupleSinkAdapter.propagateModifyChildLeftTuple(SingleLeftTupleSinkAdapter.java:260)
at org.drools.reteoo.FromNode.checkConstraintsAndPropagate(FromNode.java:355)
at org.drools.reteoo.FromNode.modifyLeftTuple(FromNode.java:299)
at org.drools.reteoo.CompositeLeftTupleSinkAdapter.propagateModifyChildLeftTuple(CompositeLeftTupleSinkAdapter.java:316)
at org.drools.reteoo.JoinNode.modifyRightTuple(JoinNode.java:286)
at org.drools.reteoo.BetaNode.modifyObject(BetaNode.java:429)
at org.drools.reteoo.JoinNode.modifyObject(JoinNode.java:459)
at org.drools.reteoo.SingleObjectSinkAdapter.propagateModifyObject(SingleObjectSinkAdapter.java:68)
at org.drools.reteoo.AlphaNode.modifyObject(AlphaNode.java:150)
at org.drools.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateModifyObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:468)
at org.drools.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.propagateModifyObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:436)
at org.drools.reteoo.AlphaNode.modifyObject(AlphaNode.java:150)
at org.drools.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateModifyObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:468)
at org.drools.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.propagateModifyObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:425)
at org.drools.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.modifyObject(ObjectTypeNode.java:287)
at org.drools.reteoo.EntryPointNode.modifyObject(EntryPointNode.java:271)
at org.drools.common.NamedEntryPoint.update(NamedEntryPoint.java:467)
at org.drools.common.NamedEntryPoint.update(NamedEntryPoint.java:370)
at org.drools.base.DefaultKnowledgeHelper.update(DefaultKnowledgeHelper.java:311) 
at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1191)
 - locked <0x00000007297a2008> (a org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda)
at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:1126)
at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1349)
at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules     (AbstractWorkingMemory.java:709)
- locked <0x00000007297a1e58> (a org.drools.reteoo.ReteooStatefulSession)
at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:673)
at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:228)
at com.healthnet.hnfs.service.rls.AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.runRules(AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.java:387)
at com.healthnet.hnfs.service.rls.AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.runAdjudicationRules(AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.java:229)
at com.healthnet.hnfs.service.rls.AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.processAuth(AuthRulesBusinessServiceImpl.java:208)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4101.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`
```

The thread dump shows that there is a Deadlock at JoinNodeLeftTuple.getLastHandle(JoinNodeLeftTuple.java:536). But as im creating seperate sessions for each request, this thread lock should not happen.

1. What could be the reason for the Deadlock
2. How can i resolve this issue

Comment: Do you mean *deadlock*? But RUNNABLE means that the thread can execute. What are the states of other threads? The location in JoinNodeLeftTuple.java doesn't appear to cause to cause a thread being blocked. - And *always* indicate the Drools version you are using.

Comment: Yes a Deadlock(Edited my question). All other threads have thrown the same message. Im using Drools 5.3. As I said this works fine with few requests but hangs with multiple requests at a time. If not Deadlock what could be the reason.

Comment: If they are all RUNNABLE you have an infinite loop. Is there a Listener attached to the session? If not, try that and see what it produces.

Comment: I already checked for that, I have **no-loop true** set so it should not fall for an infinite loop.

Comment: **This is a misapprehension.** You can easily fall into an infinite loop with no-loop on every rule. What are the last 20 entries of a listener registering activations? What is the code in the rules?

Comment: Also, try `int fired = session.fireAllRules( N )` with `N` being a reasonable limit and check whether `fired == N`: this would indicate an  infinite loop.

Comment: I dont have listener registered, I will try it.
Its a set of rules under a rule flow group which evaluates a set of objects. If it falls for infinite loop it should have happened for a single request, But its happening only in the case of multiple requests. And more over i'm creating fresh knowledge session for each request.

Comment: Post the rules and the data causing the whatever-it-is.